# use-package won't load

Tags: init-file, use-package

I use the same configuration of emacs on multiple machines, and I want to use use-package to keep the packages the same on all machines.  I have an init file in each machine's home directory that looks like this:

```
;;Set the custom file to Dropbox .emacscommon
(setq custom-file "~/Dropbox/.emacs.d/.emacscommon")

;;These are commands that should be common across systems.

(load "~/Dropbox/.emacs.d/.emacscommon")
```

And the beginning of .emacscommon has these lines:

```
;;; -*- mode: Emacs-Lisp; -*-

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

(use-package auto-package-update
  :config
  (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)
  (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t)
  (auto-package-update-maybe))
```

When I start up Emacs, though, I get the following error.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/basil/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, use-package
```

Checking the value of "load-path" via "describe-variable" gives a long list which includes "/Users/basil/.emacs.d/elpa/use-package-20190405.2047", so use-package appears to be accessible.  Why can't Emacs find it?  If I omit the use-package lines from .emacscommon, all other packages work just fine.

Comment: Do you compile `.emacscommon`?

Comment: Not sure the difference between compiling and loading.  In my .emacs, I just tell it to load .emacscommon.  Are you saying I shouldn't embed "require 'usepackage" in the eval-when-compile function?

Comment: I just tried commenting out all of the lines I displayed above in my .emacscommon, and replacing them with (require 'usepackage).  I get the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need a more complete "bootstrap" of `use-pacakge`. This is what I've picked up from somewhere else on SE.

```lisp
;;{{{ Set up package and use-package

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(eval-after-load 'gnutls
  '(add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'bind-key)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

;;}}}
```

First we load the `package` package, add MELPA, and initialize `package`. Then we add certs to gnutls. Next we test if *Emacs thinks that `use-package` is installed*, and install it otherwise. Note this is different than just seeing the package on our filesystem or in our `load-path`. I think that this is the key that you're missing.

Additionally, I'd recommend against using `custom-file` to store your "secondary init file". Experience has taught me that I'm happier if I give Emacs its own place to save settings. This is especially true when you put your init files under version control. Set it to a filename that you understand, and let Emacs read and write from it as necessary. So, in your case I'd do something like.

The init file on each machine:

```lisp
;; this is my ~/.emacs.d/init.el

;; my common emacs settings are here
(load (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/emacs.d/emacs-common-init.el"))
```

The init file common to every machine:

```lisp
;; this is my ~/Dropbox/emacs.d/emacs-common-init.el"

;; prepend personal lisp directory to the load-path
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/emacs.d/lisp"))

;; set a `custom-file` so Emacs leaves my init file alone
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "~/.Dropbox/emacs.d/emacs-common-custom.el"))

;; Set up package and use-package

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(eval-after-load 'gnutls
  '(add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'bind-key)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

;; set up my nifty packages, themes, etc. 
;; [...]
```

Comment: This works great for me.  I still don't fully understand it though - why wouldn't something like this be in the documentation?  Does my multiple machine setup complicate this?  But it seems that syncing across machines would be a very common use of use-package.